# How to ignore an empty constraint in SQL SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple MySQL database that I am querying from PHP. I have a user input some constraints in via a form, and then want to return results from a SELECT query based on the constraints. What I have is working when both constraints are used. However, if one of the constraints is not specified by the user, the SELECT query is returning no results, which I think is because it seeing the constraint variable as empty.

How do I get the SELECT query to use the constraint if it is not empty, but to ignore it if it is empty?

Here is what I tried earlier but it isn't working. I thought I could test for empty and use OR to ignore it.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM food_items 
WHERE (type IN ('$foodtypes') OR ('$foodtypes') > '') 
AND ('$budget' > '' OR cost <= ('$budget')) 
";
```

In this example, type and cost are fields in the database and $foodtypes and $budget are variables taken from the user inputs.

Thanks

Comment: Build the query dynamically and only query for the values passed in. You also appear to be open to SQL injections. Should use parameterized queries.

Comment: and you probably meant to do `'$budget' = '' OR cost <= ('$budget')` (and the same with foodtypes). (notice the = instead of >.)

Comment: Note: don't use the word `constraint` :it has a different meaning in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should build your query differently based on the value of the constraints:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM food_items WHERE " .
   ($foodtypes != "" ? "type IN ('$foodtypes')" : "TRUE") . " AND " .
   ($budget ? "cost <= $budget" : "TRUE") . " AND " .
.. and so on ..
```

**Security note:** Always escape your SQL strings before using (see mysqli_real_escape_string).